# Selenium Find By Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I tried to crawl data:

1. web ("https://www.vietnamworks.com/data-analyst+tai-ho-chi-minh-v29-vn")
2. use xpath by selenium
3. get all job title

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\trungkien.hoang\\Desktop\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get('https://www.vietnamworks.com/data-analyst+tai-ho-chi-minh-v29-vn')
sleep(5)

job_title = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"job-item")]//h3/a')
print(job_title.text)
```

With my above code i cannot crawl all job title

**Please help me to check or refer another one (by selenium or scrapy) for my aim. Thanks all**

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\trungkien.hoang\\Desktop\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get('https://www.vietnamworks.com/data-analyst+tai-ho-chi-minh-v29-vn')
sleep(5)

job_title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"job-item")]')
print(job_title.text)
```

It will help you.

Comment: Thank you but i tried your way but i just don't have any result,
Error like:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trungkien.hoang\Desktop\VNW\VNW_2.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(job_title.text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @StevenK Traceback (most recent call last) is different error  may be related to you driver Path because in C# with same XPath it's working fine..